# Display the displayName view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, display, viewbag

```
public enum  SmsType
{
    [Display(Name = "خبری")]
        Name=0,
    [Display(Name = "عادی")]
    Standard=1,

}

 public IActionResult Index()
{
 ViewBag.SmsType=new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(SmsType)));
    
    return View();
}
```

In the view

`

I want it to be displayed in the displayName view?It can also be displayed selectively in the view
I need help.

Comment: What's your view code ? And what's result do you want ? Could you explain more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want it like below ?

in the view:

```
<select  asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<SmsType>()">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you, my problem is solved